# is it possible filter nested object by value of some property?(JS)

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I'm developing my own project with JS, python, and data from open API. Bringing data from API was not that tricky even for a newbie like me. However, I got trouble (like always) in making data into useful information for me.

below is a part of I'm having a struggle with,

```
AA:array(60)
[
0:{A:2016-01-01, B:12}
1:{A:2016-02-01, B:122}
2:{A:2016-03-01, B:162}
3:{A:2016-04-01, B:129}
.
.
.
n:{A:20NN-NN-NN, B:923}
]
```

as you can see it is an array that has many objects in it. every object has the same property key A,B A is literal which has date info, and B has some numerical value. What I want to make is create new objects which have year's information. in other words, new object's has all same month and day info and only the year is different in A. And B would be the sum of the same year's B (sorry for bad explaining I'm not good at English ngl).
so above example would be like below.

```
newAA: array(5)
[
0:{A:2016-01-01, B:numeric value(sum of all 2016's B in above example)}
1:{A:2017-01-01, B:numeric value(sum of all 2017's B in above example)}
2:{A:2018-01-01, B:numeric value(sum of all 2018's B in above example)}
3:{A:2019-01-01, B:numeric value(sum of all 2019's B in above example)}
4:{A:2020-01-01, B:numeric value(sum of all 2020's B in above example)}
]
```

Honestly, This is quite tricky for me and I do not know how to handle it to make into what I want to
If you have a good idea to do this, please let me know, your help will be appreciated.

thx for reading!

Comment: You could do this with [Array.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can iterate over the array while updating a [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) where the `year` is the `key` and an object is the `value`.

The result would be the values of this Map which is a list of grouped objects by the `year` containing its first `A` in the original array and total `B`:

```js
const AA = [ {A:'2016-01-01', B:12}, {A:'2016-02-01', B:122}, {A:'2016-03-01', B:162}, {A:'2016-04-01', B:129} ];

const res = [...
  AA.reduce((map, { A, B }) => {
    const [year] = A.split('-');
    const yearRecord = map.get(year);
    if(yearRecord) yearRecord.B += B;
    else map.set(year, { A, B })
    return map;
  }, new Map)
  .values()
];

console.log(res);
```

EDIT: Same solution using object:

```js
const AA = [ {A:'2016-01-01', B:12}, {A:'2016-02-01', B:122}, {A:'2016-03-01', B:162}, {A:'2016-04-01', B:129} ];

const res = Object.values(
  AA.reduce((map, { A, B }) => {
    const [year] = A.split('-');
    const yearRecord = map[year];
    if(yearRecord) yearRecord.B += B;
    else map[year] = { A, B };
    return map;
  }, {})
);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!! your code works so well! but I have another problem because of a lack of my skill so I posted another post. could you read it too if it doesn't bother that much please?? again thanks for your help!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70030041/i-got-mapiterator-from-result-of-map-can-i-make-it-into-arrayjs

Comment: @user15508209 I'm not sure how/where you're running it so you're not getting the same output as above, but I added the same solution using an object instead of a Map to the answer, so you can try it..